# Multi-temporal stack does not include all bands

Tags: python, gdal, multi-band

I made a stack of images for a multitemporal series for 7 months (one per month with 5 bands) with gdal, but the stack that comes out to me consists of a single band for each month, probably the first.
How can I include all 5 bands for the 7 months?

Here's my code:

```
outtif = 'C:\Users\tack.tif'

tifs = [
     r'C:\Users\19_4_2018.tif',
     r'C:\Users\4_5_2018.tif',
     r'C:\Users\23_6_2018.tif',
     r'C:\Users\18_7_2018.tif',
     r'C:\Users\22_8_2018.tif',
     r'C:\Users\21_9_2018.tif',
     r'C:\Users\31_10_2018.tif'
   ] 

outds = gdal.BuildVRT(tifs, separate=True)
outds = gdal.Translate(outtif, outds)
outds=None
```